# Can't center the element vs vertical-align AND display: table-cell

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

First, see screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iARf.png

I'm use this code:

```
<div class="c-news-menu sub">
  <div class="articles-submenu-title active">Оформление ОСАГО</div>
  <div class="articles-submenu-title">Калькулятор ОСАГО</div>
  <div class="articles-submenu-title">Страховые компании</div>
</div>

.c-news-menu.sub
{
    display:table !important;   /* only 3 line in all code has !important */
}
.c-news-menu .articles-submenu-title {
    width: 166px;
    height: 37px;
    padding: 5px 10px 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: table-cell !important;     /* It doesn't work,
    vertical-align: middle !important;   * but must work correctly */
    /* margin: auto 0; NO, becose auto is 0 for top and bottom */
    /* line-height: 30px; NO, becose have no single line */
    /* padding-top: 30px; NO, becose line may be 1 or 2, so height of parent changed, need fix */
    /* text-align: center; NO, becose only horisontal align, need vertical */
}
```

What am I doing wrong or do not understand?

Comment: Where is the `height` of the cell?

Comment: .articles-submenu-title { height: 37px; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a workaround

HTML:

```
<div class="c-news-menu sub">
    <div id="c-news-group-buy-osago" class="articles-submenu-title active"><p>Оформление ОСАГО</p></div>
    <div id="c-news-group-calc-osago" class="articles-submenu-title"><p>Калькулятор ОСАГО</p></div>
    <div id="c-news-group-company-osago" class="articles-submenu-title"><p>Страховые компании</p></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.articles-submenu-title
{
    display:table; /* you maybe need !important here if you have another display rule somewhere else for this class */
}

.articles-submenu-title p
{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

I wrapped the text inside the articles-submenu-title in a `<p>`

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z9yEQ/)

Comment: @x-positive did you do it to `.c-news-menu`, i edited my error.

Comment: yes, and i'm try different elements via inspector, different values, but no results

Comment: i'm add this code in my site and in my question too

Comment: i'm just try !important, because my rules don't work permanently. With <p> inside, text have some space from above, but when i'm edit css rule, text again was in top. Can I send link to the page of site, so you can see all the code through special tools?

Comment: @x-positive sure send link

Comment: @x-positive the problem is that vertical-align doesn't work with float, so you have to use line-height. this may not be a good idea but it works: `#c-news-group-buy-osago, #c-news-group-calc-osago, #c-news-group-osago-etc { line-height:2.5em; }`

Comment: @x-positive also you have a misspelling at `c-news-atricles`

Comment: Thanks. This crutch, but perhaps this is the best solution in this situation. I will consider their relationship with the "float" in the future.

Comment: where and what misspelling

Comment: @x-positive in HTML search for "c-news-atricles"

Comment: Oh, thank you, I did not see it, even when looked at point blank)